# Predict numerical value when each variable is a target and a predictor

Tags: predictive-modeling

Imagine I have created a tabular dataset when each row is a company and each variable is the company's rating between 0 through 100 given by a rating agency.  Each of the ratings agencies can decide who they cover, so some might not cover a company leaving it blank.  Please look at example below:
C = Company
R = Rating agency

```
   | R1 | R2 | R3 |
---------------
C1 | 80 | 51 | 
C2 |    | 35 | 23
C3 | 60 |    | 45
```

I want to know what the score would have been had the rating agency covered that company using the relationship between the rating agency. In data science terms, How can I predict the missing scores for each company when the target variable is also the predictor variable. how should I approach this?

### UPDATE

Seems like this is a standard Recommender systems question, however, I have added an extra question about using a system of models, one model for each of the rating agencies.  Could that possibly work better?  Look in comment section

Comment: is there a logical reason why a rating agency would not rate a company? For example, if a rating agency only works with tech companies, trying to predict a value for a publishing company will give an incorrect result. If there are features like company size however, they *may* be able to span across multiple industries

Comment: looks like a straight-forward `recommender system` type problem

Comment: This is exactly a recommender system problem

Comment: @MattR  Well, just look at the credit rating agencies or investment analysis, these agencies get to choose who they cover and they all don't cover the same companies.  I'm not 100% what the criterias are, but I would assume company size is important.

Comment: @oW_   and Yohanes    Great lead thanks. I wanted to ask, if the number of rating agencies were small lets say 5, would a system of models work? could it possibly be better? in other words, one model to predict the missing values for each of the agencies.  Also, would one of make your response an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: could you update your question so we can move this out of the comment section? thanks :)

Comment: @oW_ Hopefully that is what you meant by updating the question

Comment: @YohanesAlfredo I wanted to tag you again to see what you thought about my comment.

Comment: @data-journey well netflix and youtube works with small sample provided by user, and are known to be quite effective but from what I read so far is that they move to more on ranking recommendation rather than predicting numerical rating like what you are looking for. Honestly speaking I am not that pro on recommender system so I cannot provide a great answer, but on hindsight what I can advice is try extending other features if that is provided that could help as well. You can look on to their paper (youtube and netflix) hopefully you can get what you are looking for.

Comment: Do lookout for collaborative filtering and factorization machine as well